# Facebook SDK does not showup in the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-login

I want to develop an application with Facebook integration ,however Facebook SDK does not show up in the properties-> android. I eliminate all errors  in Facebook SDK and click isLibrary check box . When I click to add button just opening an empty box. I tried clean project and  I close and open eclipse several times nothing change . Can you tell me what should I do now?

Comment: Imo, save you some time, use android Studio. Dependencies will be much easier to manage using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked that sdk to be used as a library,right click on fbsdk properties->android->check is library that's it

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand.I download sdk from facebook and import as existing anroid project. how should i check?

Comment: right click on facebook sdk goto properties from the left side pane window select android you will get multiple options like to switch android version also a check box using which you can set your or any other project to act as a library